# dates with "and" at the last date freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I have a list of dates seperated by comas. but I want an "and" before the last date.
I want it to look like this:

date, date, date **and** (last)date.

my code:

```
<#list MySequence as x>${x}<#sep>,</#list>
```

cant figure how to find the last date and add the "and" to it

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could decide based on the current index:

```
<#list MySequence as x>${x}<#sep><#if x?index == MySequence?size - 2> and <#else>, </#if></#list>
```

It's not very terse... so if you will do this often, create a macro for it.